# not working post form in ie

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, asp.net-ajax

i use ASP.NET MVC and this my form code:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendPeso", "Transfer", null, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "SendPeso", OnBegin = "BeginSending", OnSuccess = "LoadLastAddedTransfer" }, new { @id = "SendPeso" }))
    {
        @Html.Partial("Market/SendPesoInput", Model)
    }
```

Nothing unusual.

And this generated html code:

```
<form action="/Transfer/SendPeso" method="post" novalidate="" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" jQuery19104576308090360941="35" data-ajax-update="#SendPeso" data-ajax-success="LoadLastAddedTransfer" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-begin="BeginSending">
```

I don't understand what is attribute **jQuery19104576308090360941="35"** in my form. When i try send from... nothing happens, but if i delete **jQuery19104576308090360941="35"** from my form in browser developer mod, all working! And this only IE

Answer (score 0):

I think may be you are using the overload method wrong way

Correct syntax is :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(string Action, string Controller, object RouteValues,AjaxOptions ajaxOptions))
```

So try as follows

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendPeso", "Transfer", new { @id = "SendPeso" }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "SendPeso", OnBegin = "BeginSending", OnSuccess = "LoadLastAddedTransfer" }))
```